Java Spring Boot back end @Async annotation not working on Azure App Service server when uploading file to Azure Storage
So we have a Spring Boot Java back end running in an Azure App Service container. Using Azure Storage Blobs to store files. In a certain controller service method, we are trying to upload a very large size file, about 200mb. The file uploads fine locally. The issue occurs when trying to upload on the Azure App Service server. Once the file upload process hits 300 seconds, the connection times out. Read that there is no way to increase this time limit due to Azure Load Balancers. Specifically in the Log Stream we see:
file connection error
To get around this. Have been trying to use Spring's @Async annotation so that the Controller returns a response immediately while the file continues to upload in the background. Made sure that the Async method is in it's own class. And made sure that in a file with the @Configuration annotation, that the @EnableAsync annotation is added. Everything seems fine when running locally and it runs Asynchronously as it should. But once it is attempted on the Azure server, then it seems the Async tag is overlooked and it runs Synchronously again. Trying to figure out what the reason for this is. Something to do with running it in the Azure App Service
This is my first post so sorry if something in my question is not formatted to the Stack Overflow standard. Thanks!
FileService.java
 public FileDTO uploadFile(FileDTO fileDTO)
    {

//Access blob container where files are stored
BlobContainerClient containerClient = new BlobContainerClientBuilder()
    .connectionString(CONNECTION_STRING)
    .containerName(fileDTO.getContainerName() + calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)+"/"+   (calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1)+"/" +calendar.get(Calendar.DATE))
    .httpClient(httpClient).buildClient();

//Create blob client which contains file data
BlobClient blob = containerClient.getBlobClient(fileDTO.getFileName());

//Upload file
FileServiceAsyncImpl fileServiceAsync1 = new FileServiceAsyncImpl();

fileServiceAsync1.uploadAsync(blob, parallelUploadOptions, timeout);
}

FileServiceAsync.java
@Async
public void uploadAsync(BlobClient blob, BlobParallelUploadOptions parallelUploadOptions, Duration timeout)
{
  //Try to upload file using parallel upload options
  Response<BlockBlobItem> response = blob.uploadWithResponse(parallelUploadOptions, timeout, null);
  //blob.upload(fileData, true);

  System.out.println("Upload Status: "+response.getStatusCode());
  System.out.println(response.getValue().toString());
}

Config.java
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class Config
{
   //Some config...
}

Tried using the @Async method and expected the file to upload Asynchronously. However while on Azure App Service it uploads Synchronously

It looks like your issue could be due to manually creating the service via FileServiceAsyncImpl fileServiceAsync1 = new FileServiceAsyncImpl();. You need to inject this service for Spring annotations to work. When you use injection, you get a Spring managed(proxied) version of the service. The proxy will include the @Async functionality. I am skeptical that the current code works as intended when running locally.

Originally that class was injected. It also didn't work when it was injected. So I tried removing the injection to see if that would change anything. It didn't. Let me put it back the way it was just to make sure.

Changed it back and it's still doing the same thing. One thing to note is the @Async annotation is on the Impl file for the service. So it is fileServiceAsync interface, and the fileServiceAsyncImpl implements it. In fileService, fileServiceAsync is now autowired at the top and injected via constructor. It does work if I run it outside of the Azure server though.

How are determining it isn't running asynchronously? Keep the injection and put some logging statements in to verify it's not running asynchronously. Logs should show the thread id before calling uploadAsync() is different than the thread id within uploadAsync().

Was just basing it on the fact that the controller method doesn't return a response immediately and waits for the Async method to finish uploading. Will try putting some logs and report back when I get the chance.

So I added some sys outs to show the thread id's. Testing locally, I see Thread Outside: 46 and Thread Inside: 60. Which seems to be working as intended. On the Azure server however I'm looking at the log stream and not seeing any of those log statements.
